# How can I deploy a website remotely as a non-administrator user to IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, webdeploy

Remote non-administrator users can't deploy a site.

I've set up the delegation, web deploy 2.0 refresh, everything. I still get `401 UNAUTHORIZED`. After about four hours now, I've been sitting here trying to figure this out. I've gone through every single help article I could find, everyone has a similar issue but a different fix. None have worked for me.

My "Administrator" account can deploy just fine.

However, there's now this other fun little issue. I have the management service in IIS manager. I can specify an IP, all except the one I want. I reinstalled IIS and all of its features and suddenly it won't let me specify my WAN IP. It will let me specify "All unassigned addresses" however. But basically it tells me it's already bound. I've confirmed no other application is using this. One forum post mentioned some registry issue with it, but of course did not list the path to the entry. I've not been able to find it.

Any tips, tricks, hints, or anything like that would be amazing.

I'm trying to web deploy out of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and I'm on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a domain controller and specifying the delegation to a domain user worked fine. Just not a system user.